# touch/resources/sass/sencha-touch/base Failed to load resource error sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

To include icons from pictos,I installed compass and updated sass, from then my app is raising following error when it is loading.After loading, everything is working fine and icons are showing up but I want to know why that error is raising.

Failed to load resource: the server not responded with a status of 404(Not Found)   touch/resources/sass/sencha-touch/base

Can some body help me on this issue.I am new to Sencha I was unable to find where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Basically 404 means it can't find the file.. is that path you posted is correct?

Comment: Where is this error showing up?  Browser console?

Comment: console but I doesn't have any effect on css  elements

Comment: `touch/resources/sass/sencha-touch/base` does not exist in Sencha Touch core lib. Can you please give a hint about what you did is related to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is purely my fault .. In index.html I added base.scss file instead of adding base.css ,that is why it raising an error.I updated my index.html and now it is working fine . Thank you for those who helped me